# iterate through dask delayed dict

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I have many delayed dict returned from a dask delayed function. I would like to aggregate them into a `summary_dict` like below. `items` function doesn't work on delayed object.

```
@dask.delayed
def get_dict(date):
    return {
        'a': {'date': date},
        'b': {'date': date}
    }

summary_dict = {}
dates = [d1, d2, d3, ...]
for date in dates:
    date_dict = get_dict(date)
    # the following doesn't work because date_dict is a delayed object
    for key, val in date_dict.items():
        summary_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
```

I'm able to do the following to make it work. However, it is quite ugly because I have to hardcode the keys ahead.

```
hardcoded_keys = ['a', 'b']
get_dict_items = {key, dask.delayed(operator.itemgetter(key)) for key in keys}

summary_dict = {}
dates = [d1, d2, d3, ...]
for date in dates:
    date_dict = get_dict(date)
    for hardcoded_key in hardcoded_keys:
        val = get_dict_items[key](date_dict)
        summary_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(val)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: `keys` is not defined in your second code block.

Comment: Also, you have `get_dict_items` and `get_dict_item`. Should both be `get_dict_items`?

Comment: it seems like you're using delayed just to store data, but then you're loading and looping through it all in series. I'm having a hard time understanding your example just because I don't understand how delayed is actually helping you here. Could you explain a bit about how you're seeing dask fit into your workflow?

Comment: I might be misreading the code, but does `summary_dict` contain just two keys ('a' and 'b')?

Comment: @joseville sorry `keys` should be `hardcoded_keys`, and `get_dict_item` should be `get_dict_items`. I just updated my question

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thanks for raising this. my actual `get_dict` function is a lot more complicated. by iterating dates, I'm parallelizing all the `get_dict` functions.

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev `summary_dict` could contain more keys, but simplified it in my example

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I might add to your solution @abisko is that Delayed objects support `__getitem__`, so instead of using `operator.itemgetter`, you should be able to index directly:

```py
from dask import delayed
from datetime import datetime


@delayed
def get_dict(date):
    return {
        'a': {'date': date},
        'b': {'date': date}
    }


summary_dict = {}
dates = [datetime.now(), datetime(2020, 1, 1), datetime(1999, 4, 23)]
date_dicts = [get_dict(d) for d in dates]
for date_dict in date_dicts:
    for key in ["a", "b"]:
        summary_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(date_dict[key])
```

It might also be worth noting that the [public Delayed API](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/delayed-api.html#dask.delayed.delayed) accepts an `nout` argument, which would support iterating through tuples, but unfortunately not dictionaries.